# Canonical definition of quotient bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, quotient-spaces, geometric-construction

For a vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$ and a subbundle $\pi':E'\to M$ of $E$ where the ranks are $r, r'$, we can define the quotient bundle $E/E'\to M$. The usual construction is to find an open cover where there is a local frame $\sigma_1, \cdots, \sigma_r$ of $E$ such that the first $r'$ sections form a local frame for $E'$, and then the rest would form a frame for $E/E'$. I understand this construction, but it looks noncanonical because the considered open cover is not very canonical.

Is there a way to canonically define the quotient bundle without such choice of open cover? And moreover, would 'canonicality' matter for applications of the quotient bundle?

Comment: You forgot to require that $E’\subset E$. Isn’t the argument you’re quoting establishing local triviality?

Comment: @Ted Thanks, I edited the question. The question was that of uniqueness, which was answered.

Comment: I believe you could also construct by defining: $E/E'=\coprod_{x\in M}E_x/E'_x$, you just need to construct an induced vector bundle atlas, which I think shouldn't be too hard. Whether or not this counts is canonical I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, the ‘best’ way to *define* such things is via a *universal property*. Universal properties take care of uniqueness, while existence is usually established by some ad-hoc method. For example, starting at the level of vector spaces first:

> **Definition/Theorem (Quotient Vector Spaces):**
>
> Let $E$ be a vector space over a field $\Bbb{F}$, and $F$ a vector subspace. Then, there is a pair $(\widetilde{E},\pi)$ where $\widetilde{E}$ is a vector space over $\Bbb{F}$ and $\pi:E\to \widetilde{E}$ is a linear map, such that the following condition is satisfied:
>
> - For any vector space $G$ over $\Bbb{F}$, and any linear map $f:E\to G$, if $F\subset \ker f$, then there is a unique linear transformation $\widetilde{f}:\widetilde{E}\to G$ such that $f=\widetilde{f}\circ \pi$ (i.e a certain diagram commutes).
>
> Moreover, the pair $(\widetilde{E},\pi)$ is *unique up to unique isomorphism*, so we simply denote it as $(E/F,\pi)$ and refer to it as *the* quotient vector space of $E$ by $F$.

The uniqueness up to unique isomorphism tells us that there is only one such vector space, modulo “implementation details” (although not a perfect analogy, I like to think of it as saying something like every language can express the same information, so an essay in English has just as much information as an Essay in French, as long as you have a dictionary to translate between the two), and also because of the uniqueness, it justifies our notation $E/F$, to express that this vector space really depends only on $E$ and $F$ (though by slight abuse of language we typically suppress mentioning $\pi$).

The existence of a vector space $E/F$ and a linear map $\pi:E\to E/F$ satisfying the condition in the bullet point is of course something which has to be done. It doesn’t matter how you do it, but once you manage to prove the existence, then you have captured all the information it has because the universal property is satisfied.

If you now replace the field $\Bbb{F}$ with $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$, and  “vector space” with “vector bundle”, “vector subspace” with “vector subbundle”, and “linear map” with “vector bundle morphism”, you get the universal definition of quotient bundles.

Such universal property-based definitions are good not only for quotients, but also for tensor products of vector spaces, and by extension, for vector bundles. You can even do it for direct sums.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice approach. Can the same approach be used for Hom bundles? I am not aware of a similar property for Hom(E,F).

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\tilde{f}:F\rightarrow G$?

Comment: @Chris I think it should be $\tilde{E} \to G$.

Comment: @Quasi07 yup you are right.

Comment: @Quasi07 I’m not sure (and I don’t think one exists). But, another thing to keep in mind is that vector bundles are at a very crude level, “just vector spaces at every point of the base”, so you just take the Hom spaces of each fiber; that already gives you the set theoretic, so one just has to prove smoothness. One thing one can do is characterize these properties in terms of smoothness of sections:

Comment: There exists on $\text{Hom}(E,F)$ a unique structure of vector bundle over a base $M$ such that the following condition is satisfied: for any rough local sections $\psi$ of $E$ and $T$ of $\text{Hom}(E,F)$ over an open set $U\subset M$, if $\psi$ and $T(\psi)$ are smooth sections of $E$ and $F$ over $U$ respectively, then $T$ is a smooth section of $\text{Hom}(E,F)$ over $U$. (This property is really what we want in applications)

Comment: and thanks for catching the typo, $f$ induces a map out of the quotient.

Comment: my bad, my phrasing in my previous comment was missing an extra universal quantifier. I should say “$T(\psi)$ is smooth for all $\psi$”.

Comment: Oh, I think that proposition is exactly what I wanted. I will try to prove uniqueness in this case. Thans for your help!